# Prove synthetically: projection of a circle onto a plane is an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, solid-geometry

I am wondering how I can prove synthetically that the projection of a circle onto a plane is an ellipse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize the projected circle as the plane section of a cone with base the unprojected circle, ie., construct the cone.

Then either take it on belief that sections of a cone are the conic sections of plane geometry (ellipse is the only bounded one, so it must be that); or repeat Dandelin's proof for this cone and plane section.